# facebook embedded url links

Tags: html, facebook, web, hyperlink

Could anyone tell me, how does Facebook (and some other sites) extract a sector of a site whose URL we provide in a form. Usually they extract a multimedia content and some title. For instance regarding Youtube video urls, it extracts the video thumbnail and the video title. As far as I'm concerned, that is done by executing an Ajax request and using an interceptor which parses the html content.

Can anyone help me to clarify this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph here is the documentation of what you want to know.

Comment: I mentioned facebook as an example, i want to integrate this functionality into my own web site. I need some ideas or any library that can do that on my behalf.

Comment: Okay, sorry i misunderstood you, try parsing the opengraph tags on your own, many pages use them and on page without opengraph tags, parse the meta tags.